# Distinguishing between two DDH-like tuples

Tags: diffie-hellman, provable-security, distinguisher, indistinguishability, reduction

Given a group generator $g$ (in a group where DDH is hard). Let $X_1=g^{x_1}$ and $X_2=g^{x_2}$ be two public elements, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are selected randomly and kept secret.

Consider a game where a challenger selects secretly some random $r$ and computes $Y_1= X_1^r$ and $Y_2=X_2^r$. The challenger hands $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to the adversary. The adversary wins the game if it distinguishes $(X_1, X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ from $(X_1,X_2,Y_2,Y_1)$.

Is there a way to prove that the adversary can't win this game with non-negligible probability (e.g., if there is there a security reduction that can be used to prove this)?

Comment: Do you mean: "adversary wins if it distinguishes $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ from $(X_1,X_2,Y_2,Y_1)$" ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I think you should use the DDH assumption to prove that both distributions are indistinguishable from uniform.

Comment: The problem is that even if they are both indistinguishable from uniform, they may still be distinguishable from one another (e.g., if $Y_1=Y_2^2$, though this case is unlikely as $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be random elements in the group).

Comment: What Mikero means is that using DDH, you can show that they are *jointly* indistinguishable from uniform.

Comment: By saying "jointly indistinguishable from uniform", do you mean that $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ is indistinguishable from $(X_1,X_2,g^{z_1},g^{z_2})$ for some random $z_1$ and $z_2$ (say random field elements)?

Comment: Indistinguishability is transitive. $\mathcal{D}_1 \approx \mathcal{U} \approx \mathcal{D}_2 \implies \mathcal{D}_1 \approx \mathcal{D}_2$.